# Log Lazy Loading operations

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

I use Entity Framework 5 with POCO entities and lazy loading proxies. In most cases I eagerly load all entities required for subsequent operations, but in some cases I rely on lazy loading to retrieve and navigate to related entities. This works well, but I would like to audit my application and make sure that I don't miss opportunities for eager loading optimization (or at least eliminate excessive use of lazy loading).

I currently rely on the SQL Profiler for this purpose, but this is tedious, because it's hard to distinguish between eager/explicit loading and lazy loading queries.

Is it possible to log lazy loading operations? Basically, I would like to Debug.Print whenever a store query is executed, as a result of lazy loading (but not when I explicitly execute a query).

Please don't provide commentary on the merits (or lack thereof) of lazy loading. I am working on a sizable application and switching at this stage would be extremely risky.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking out this library: https://github.com/jamesmanning/EntityFramework.LazyLoadLoggingInterceptor

More specifically, [this file](https://github.com/jamesmanning/EntityFramework.LazyLoadLoggingInterceptor/blob/master/EntityFramework.LazyLoadLoggingInterceptor/LazyLoadLoggingInterceptor.cs) shows an implementation of an Entity Framework `DbCommandInterceptor` capable of detecting lazy loading queries. At its core, it implements a `ReaderExecuting` method containing this hack:

```
        // unfortunately not a better way to detect whether the load is lazy or explicit via interceptor
        var stackFrames = new StackTrace(true).GetFrames();
        var stackMethods = stackFrames?.Select(x => x.GetMethod()).ToList();

        var dynamicProxyPropertyGetterMethod = stackMethods?
            .FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.DeclaringType?.FullName.StartsWith("System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies") == true &&
                x.Name.StartsWith("get_"));
        if (dynamicProxyPropertyGetterMethod == null)
        {
            // not in a lazy-load context, nothing to do
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this tool. https://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/ You can get it from Nuget. Available for MVC and desktop applications (search for mini profiler for command application). Tells you SQL, time of execution and code where it was called. Free. Excellent tool.

It won't tell you which query was lazy-loaded, but you can target particular parts of code, hence you should be able to see which code calls which queries.